# Django Model design for train routes

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

I would like to store multiple stations and multiple trains in my database. I was planning to have each station as one model and each train as one model.

But i would like to understand how should we store each train route in a dynamic way using the station models.

For Example, we have Stations A, B , C , D, E

And Train t1 route is A-C-B-D-E
And Train t2 route is A-B-E

So i would like to store these train route under each row of train model. Could someone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Bit hard to say without additional information but it sounds like you need another table called routes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you from a data model stand point.

```
class Station(models.Model):
    pass

class Route(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        # Specify that the train and index are unique together to prevent
        # any duplicate stations at the same index value at the db level.
        # You'll probably want to validate this in the application logic as well.
        unique_together = ('station', 'index')
    station = models.ForeignKey('train.Station')
    train = models.ForeignKey('train.Train')
    index = models.IntegerField()

class Train(models.Model):
    stations = models.ManyToManyField('train.Station', through=Route)
```

Answer (score 0):

With your approach you think of stations as if they were all connected. For each station you could have a **many2many field**, that allows you to "connect" stations with each other. 
You then could use three models:

- Trains
- Routes
- Stations

Stations are connected to stations. Routes have a starting and an ending point. Trains are related to routes (since one train can run on multiple routes, or one route can transport multiple trains).
You also could programmatically calculate (graphs) how many stations which train has to take between start and goal.

Comment: actually each train has a fixed route with stops, start station and end station. We can think it as a local train does too and fro in the same route for example metro trains in city where journey time is less than 1-2 hours